# New appstore Review guidelines issue

Tags: iphone, paypal, appstore-approval

I need some help for iphone application,i have some question regarding the new iOS development guidelines.

Please take a look here first.
http://www.scribd.com/doc/37160656/App-Store-Review-Guidelines-App-Store-Resource-Center

The point 11.1 & 11.2 states below are the points on which i seek more clarifications.

11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected.

I am working on the ipad application in which we need to include paypal mobile payment api from here. x(dot)com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile.

So is it valid or not to use this API , as its seems against the point 11.2.

And the application on which we working is also include the pdf format download from webservices to the application after paypal payment process.

Please guide me on this.

Looking forward to hearing back from you soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are selling goods/services to be used WITHIN the application you MUST use in app purchase.

If you are selling physical goods/services or goods/services to be consumed outside of the application then you MAY NOT use in app purchase. (see 11.3)

Therefore if you're selling a PDF that will be downloaded into the app you HAVE TO use IAP.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for valuable update, i worked on some another solution, please share your view on this.  After making and paypal payment, we send a password protected pdf to user through email ,and put some code mechanism a user can only open that pdf only from ipad memory. How Apple will react on this?

Comment: if you're saying "do you think I can trick apple?" then the answer is "of course you can, but when they find out what you're doing they'll most probably remove your app and kick you off the developer program". Why don't you just do it the normal way?